# Spring Data JPA Query - count with in clause

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement the following query with spring data JPA with method name resolving.

```
select count(*) from example ex where ex.id = id and ex.status in (1, 2);
```

I know there's a method in crud repo for count which will go like - `countByIdAndStatus(params)` but I wasn't sure how can I incorporate "in" clause with this method.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
long countByIdAndStatusIn(Integer id, List<Type> params);
```

With `@Query`:

```
@Query("select count(*) from Example ex where ex.id = ?1 and ex.status in (?2)")
long countByIdAndStatus(Integer id, List<Type> params);
```